# If $\lvert\ker(\varphi)\rvert=p$ and $p$ is prime, then $G=\ker(\varphi)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, prime-numbers, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I have a group $G$ and a random subgroup $H\leq G$. Also I have a homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\rightarrow H$. If $\lvert\ker(\varphi)\rvert=p$ and $p$ is prime can you help me how I can prove $G=\ker{(\varphi)}$? I try with the First Group Isomorphism Theorem but I could not do anything.

Comment: Maybe Your question is wrong .Related question index of Kernal = prime that $|G:Ker \phi|$=p then $ker \phi =G$

Answer (score 5):

This is not true, take $p:G\times G\rightarrow G$ the projection where the cardinal of $G$ is prime.

Comment: $p$ is already a prime number :) (just kidding)

Comment: Use, say, $\pi$ instead of $p$, @TsemoAristide